# Generate data on one phone and retrieve on another using Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct, service-discovery

I want to have one phone generating some data, like random numbers, and have another phone connect to it and start receiving the data. So one phone is acting kind of like a sensor except with data that doesn't mean anything and the other one wants to retrieve the data. I want to do this using Wi-Fi Direct. I'm reading the only real tutorials I can find on Wi-Fi Direct [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html) and I sort of understand how it works as far as making connections and service discovery but I don't know where to go from there. I guess I need to do something with sockets...but it's hard to find examples similar to what I want to do. Can anyone maybe point me to something relevant or explain a little about how to do this with Wi-Fi Direct? I'm just a beginner trying to learn through a lot of googling. I'm sorry for not providing much info other than an idea but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to make a simple client/server program to transfer data between devices over WiFi. Please review the [link](http://xelsoft.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/simple-tcp-client-server-communication-using-android/) for simple data sending and receiving example.